# Encoding dataset index presents a type-error, why? [Machine Learning]

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, encoding

Dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBdyMv8yU7EEdlUNqk_Ox9gT2LMItY2DivEiVX4fYWY/edit?usp=sharing

So I am trying to apply machine learning to the stats in the dataset, however every time I try to encode/pre-process the data I am left with receiving:

`TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations`

Isn't the point of preprocessing to change the values? & isn't that a necessary precursor to apply machine learning? Don't know how to go about encoding/preprocessing... any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks !

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

from sklearn import datasets, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score



dbdata = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Andrew/sportsref_download.xlsx")

print(dbdata)
print(dbdata.describe())
df = dbdata.columns
print(df)

#define x&y
x = dbdata
y = dbdata.PTS

shapes = x.shape, y.shape
print(shapes)

print(dbdata.index)
print('next')

#apply logreg
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')

cross_val_score(logreg, x, y, cv=2, scoring='accuracy').mean()
print(cross_val_score)

le = LabelEncoder()
df["date_tf"] = le.fit_transform(dbdata.Date)
df["tm_tf"] = le.fit_transform(df.Tm)
df["opp_tf"] = le.fit_transform(df.Opp)

OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df[['date_tf']]).toarray()

Cols = ["Date","Tm","Opp"]
integer_encoded = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(x[Cols])



scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)
print(X_scaled)

ec = OneHotEncoder()
X_encoded = dbdata.apply(lambda col: ec.fit_transform(col.astype(str)), axis=0, result_type='expand')
X_encoded = ec.fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1), y)


print(X_encoded)
X_encoded = ec.fit_transform(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error is because the model has been fit before the non-numeric values have been encoded.**

You are feeding the model data in date format, which sadly will not work.
ML models of this nature only take numeric or binary data.

[Sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html)

**Data pre-processing** is one of the most important parts of building and deploying a model into production.

If you need help cleaning the data, just drop a message. I would be happy to help.

Otherwise, refer here: [Intro article on data cleaning](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-data-cleaning-how-to-process-data-for-analytics-and-machine-learning-modeling-c2afcf4fbf45)

Comment: as this is my first project of this nature could you help clean the data... just so I know how to approach things moving forward?

Comment: Ok, I'll send this to you by the end of today, have you got an email that I can use to reach you and send you the code and documentation when I'm finished?

Comment: @truee If you have been contacted, can you please remove your email address?

Comment: @user16524074 i did & how come?

Comment: @truee - Thanks! You don't want bots scanning the site and then sending you spam

Comment: Thanks for the help !!!!